# Is is possible to represent a firestore Query as string

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It is possible to represent a      `CollectionReference` as a string with the getter proprety `path` .
This is very handy for unit tests.
For example `admin.firestore().collection('cities').doc('LA').path` returns `"cities/LA"`

What about `Query` represented as String ?

For example is there a way to something like this `admin.firestore().collection('cities').where('name','==','LA').toString()` to print something like this this: `"cities/{where $name=='LA'}"`

This would be handy for unit testing

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  You will have to build and parse the string yourself.  The SDK won't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/api/Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.html) document, you can see that the inherited members of class Query uses toString. Is this what you are looking for?