# Is there a way to convert firestore queries to string?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a web app that relies heavily on Firestore's live snapshots and I want to optimize it a bit. Specifically, I want to build a `Map` of queries that already have a running subscription to them so that next time a piece of code wants to subscribe to the exact same query, it can check that and just use the existing subscription if it happens to exist.

But for that I need to have a way to identify a Firestore query. I thought the simplest way would be to convert the query to a string. I was hoping `JSON.stringify(query)` would do the trick, but it doesn't work, because it complains about circular references.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339651/is-is-possible-to-represent-a-firestore-query-as-string?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried that, but `query.toString()` only returns `[object Object]`

Comment: Did you see the comment by Doug Stevenson on the post that @FrankvanPuffelen linked to?

Comment: @GregFenton ah, now I did. Okay well I do have a working solution for now. `JSON.stringify(query._queryOptions || query.jd)`. The `.jd` comes from the minified browser version of firestore (as opposed to `firebase-admin`). I just wonder how often `.jd` will become something else when I update...

Comment: If you have a solution, then please answer your own question to explain what you've done that works for you.